# ValueError: listdir: path too long for Windows

Tags: python, windows, pandas, dataframe

EDIT: SOLUCIONADO: El problema es que estaba considerando la basepath como archivo y no como carpeta. Aprovecho de agradecer a abulafia por hacerme ver el error. adjunto codigo para el que le interese:

```
import pyprind
import pandas as pd
import os

basepath = 'C:/aclImdb'

labels = {'pos': 1, 'neg': 0}
pbar = pyprind.ProgBar(50000)
df = pd.DataFrame()
for s in ('test', 'train'):
    for l in ('pos', 'neg'):
        path = os.path.join(basepath, s, l)
        for file in os.listdir(path):
            with open(os.path.join(path, file), 'r', encoding='utf-8') as infile:
                txt = infile.read()
            df = df.append([[txt, labels[l]]], ignore_index=True)
            pbar.update()
df.columns = ['review', 'sentiment']
```

He estado estudiando un libro de machine learning y me enfrento a este error que aun no puedo solucionar: `ValueError: listdir: path too long for Windows`, recurro a ustedes para ver si me pueden ayudar con esto, gracias

He probado con descargar un software que se llama longpath tool , y un par de cosas más pero aun no puedo resolverlo. si alguien me ilumina seria e mucha ayuda saludos

> The IMDB movie review set can be downloaded from http://ai.stanford.edu/~amaas/data/sentiment/. After downloading the dataset, decompress the files.

El codigo es:

````
import pyprind
import pandas as pd
import os
from sys import argv
path = pd.read_csv("data", header=None)
path.head(3)

pbar = pyprind.ProgBar(50000)
labels = {'pos':1, 'neg':0}

path = path.to_string()

for s in ('test', 'train'):
    for l in ('pos', 'neg'):
        path = os.path.join(path, s, l)
        for file in os.listdir(path):
            with open(os.path.join(path,'r', encoding='utf-8')) as infile:
                txt = infile.read()
            path = path.append([[txt, labels[l]]], ignore_index=True)
            pbar.update()
path.columns = ['review', 'sentiment']

el error es:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-d83afc0ae5a8> in <module>
      2     for l in ('pos', 'neg'):
      3         path = os.path.join(path, s, l)
----> 4         for file in os.listdir(path):
      5             with open(os.path.join(path,'r', encoding='utf-8')) as infile:
      6                 txt = infile.read()

ValueError: listdir: path too long for Windows  ```
````

Comment: alvar, tu pregunta no va a ser bien recibida a menos que pongas el código y el error como texto. Es algo molesto tener que volver a escribir manualmente todo lo que tienes en tu ventana...

Comment: tienes razón ... no pensé en eso, la voy a editar ahora , gracias!

Comment: Me estoy perdiendo... tal como empieza el código la variable `path` es un datframe. Por tanto supongo que tendrá varias filas, columnas, etc... Pero poco después lo conviertes en una cadena lo que generará un texto con las celdas separadas por tabuladores, y las filas separadas por retornos de carro. Una cadena que supongo larguísima (en realidad dependerá de cuántas filas tenga la tabla), y que obviamente no es un nombre de directorio, pero más adelante lo intentas usar como si lo fuera...

Comment: La convertí a str porque antes me daba otro error que decia : typeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not DataFrame y ahora cambió a este error.

Comment: ¿Pero qué es lo que contiene el csv que has leido? ¿Por qué lo intentas usar como si fuera un nombre de carpeta?

Comment: es un base de datos de peliculas, ahi arriba dejé el link ... la verdad no sé mucho de código soy más estadístico y me he guíado por un libro que se llama Python Machine Learning de Sebastian Raschka. Gracias por el interés de ayudar y saludos.

Comment: Yo no veo que en esa url haya ningún csv. Lo que hay es un `tar.gz` que una vez descomprimido genera centenares de ficheros organizados en carpetas, pero no he encontrado por ningún sitio el csv (que llamas "data" en tu código)

Comment: te adjunto link de la data

Comment: este si https://transfernow.net/71gkm0l2mpev

Comment: Madre mia! El csv en cuestión ocupa 63MB y tiene 5000 filas! Y nada dentro de él puede considerarse un nombre de carpeta. Sólo es texto. Al leerlo con pandas y luego convertirlo en cadena, has generado un string con más de 65862309 caracteres. Y luego pasas ese string como parámetro a `os.listdir()` que espera un nombre de carpeta. No es de extrañar que se queje de que el nombre de la carpeta es demasiado largo! XDD En realidad, no tengo ni idea de qué pretendes hacer, pero creo que no necesitas leer ese csv, y que como path debes usar el nombre de la carpeta donde descargaste el dataset.

Comment: Parece que es un problema de memoria, que podría hacer? memoria externa ? instalar otro sistema operativo?

Comment: Que no, que no es nada de eso! Es que el contenido del csv no es un nombre de carpeta, es otra cosa. Creo que sería mejor que empezaras por decir qué es lo que quieres hacer. El código que has puesto tiene dos partes. En una lees el csv. En otra intentas leer un montón de ficheros. Cada parte por separado estaría bien **si no fuera** porque los ficheros los intentas leer de una carpeta que no existe, y que has sacado del csv, concatenando en un solo string todo su contenido. Ese csv, repito una vez más, **no es un nombre de carpeta**.

Comment: Prueba a cambiar la línea `path=path.to_string()` por `path="."`, para que use como nombre de carpeta la actual. Y elimina `path = pd.read_csv("data", header=None)` o al menos cambia el nombre de la variable en la que lo lees y no la llames `path`, que el path es otra cosa.

Comment: Tienes razón, el problema era que estaba leyendo un archivo y no un nombre de carpeta , muchisimas gracias.